# SharePoint 2010 Bread Crumb Navigation

Tags: breadcrumb

Is there a way to remove the bread crumb navigation in SharePoint 2010? Basically I don't want to see the site and subsite titles next to the logo that keep growing across the top portion of the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the breadcrumb control from the master page. If you want to do it for just few pages, override the content placeholder from master in which breadcrumb resides.

Answer (score 2):

To remove *both* site and subsite titles next to the logo, use this style.

```
.s4-titletext
{
    display: none;
}
```

Or with jQuery

```
$(".s4-titletext").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following CSS worked for me without a problem:

```
.s4-titletext h2,
.s4-titlesep
{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do is create a custom master page with 
as follow:

1. Create a new project
2. Configure as a Sandbox Solution
3. Add a new Module to your project
4. Download a copy of Seattle.master
5. Add the copy to your module, rename to CustomMaster.master, and Change your elements.xml file to point to _catalogs\masterpage folder
6. Search for "ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox", you will go to this line :

   add style="display:none;" so the tag will become
7. now search for "ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox"
   and the line after -
8. save the file -> build -> deply
9. in site settings change your master page as newly deployed master page and 
   you will not see the breadcrumb